a few questions on stratified analysis

If one of the 3 stratification factor from IWRS has data errors, should we replace it with CRF collected baseline values? Will this break the balance of the strata blocks?

For non ITT population, say, per protocol population which has about 15% patients less than ITT, can we still perform stratified analysis using the factors in randomization?

If randomization has 3 factors; when we do subgroup analysis using one factor, can we use the other 2 stratification factors for stratified analysis?


Thank you.

Could you please explain the acronyms you're using?

To answer your questions it's relevant to recall why we stratify: these factors are usually prognostic for the outcome, and stratification is there to guard against too spurious allocation imbalances in them due to sampling effects in finite (and often smaller) studies. To further realize their statistical efficiency it is common and accepted practice to adjust your model for them.
Aside, three stratification factors is on the higher end of what is usually advised, especially if each of them has multiple levels. This quickly becomes an operational challenge and with more strata you simply need more subjects to fill all of them, counteracting the goal of balancing smaller samples.
With that in mind, and including some annotations for the  acronyms:

If one of the 3 stratification factor from IWRS [the central randomization system] has data errors, should we replace it with CRF [investigator-provided] collected baseline values? Will this break the balance of the strata blocks?

If the central and CRF stratum values don't match it is likely that not following the actual randomization list will cause slight changes to allocation balance. There is no truly right approach here, but I would prefer the correct stratum over strict allocation balance due to the former's prognostic power. Keep in mind that your study likely won't be (and doesn't have to be) perfectly balanced in its allocation for various other reasons anyway.
If there's more than a tiny fraction of mistakes in randomization strata they might more or less cancel out randomly as far as allocation is concerned, and even then you probably have bigger issues to worry about than balance if that were the case.

For non ITT [intent-to-treat, i.e. all randomized] population, say, per protocol population which has about 15% patients less than ITT, can we still perform stratified analysis using the factors in randomization?

Yes, you should still adjust for strata for the reason mentioned above.

If randomization has 3 factors; when we do subgroup analysis using one factor, can we use the other 2 stratification factors for stratified analysis?

As above, I would indeed keep the adjustment for the remaining strata. The larger issue with these last two questions is one I already alluded to above; the more strata you have the smaller the number of subjects will be in each individual one, which defeats their goal of achieving balance. The same is true for subgroups in general, the smaller you slice your data the less powerful your analysis will become and the more you'll be exposed to sampling effects. Still, if your strata are sufficiently large and indeed relevant for the outcome you would expect to gain from adjusting for them.

Thank you very much. Your answers are very informative!
